# (T-SQL): How do I use result set A to calculate result set B?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, resultset

I have 2 queries, A and B, which I currently use independently from each other. They both return an employee ID and some metric values. I now want to use the employee IDs returned from result set A in query B.

A's query is structured like this:

```
select employee_id from employee where employee_team = 1 and employee_role = 1
```

B's query is structured like this:

```
declare @tester int = 123450 --plug in employee ID
select employee_id
,employee_name
,sum(case 
  when notes.note_author!=employee_id and logs.log_date<@today 
  then 1 else 0 end) as metric
from notes
inner join note_to_log_bridge as br on notes.note_id=br.note_id
inner join logs on br.log_id=logs.log_id
inner join employee on employee_id=@Tester
```

If I want to get B's metrics for 5 employees, I have to run query B 5 times, changing the @Tester variable each time. I'd like to instead find some way of automating that, so that I get the metrics for query B for every employee_id in result set A.

I tried stored result set A as a CTE and using a while loop to run through query B:

```
declare @line=1
with cte (employee_id) as <query_a>
while (@line<=count(cte.employee_id))
begin <query b>...
```

I never finished this query because I discovered that `while` cannot follow the creation of a CTE.

I tried using a table variable:

```
declare @set_a (employee_id int)
insert into @set_a <query a>
```

but when I try to use `@set_a` in query B, I get a message saying that I need to declare the scalar variable @set_a.

I tried using a temp table and got a "could not be bound" error.

I am out of ideas. Am I approaching this problem in anything resembling the right direction? Is this even possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Wrap the code into a procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Cursor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx) ?

> If I want to get B's metrics for 5 employees, I have to run query B 5
>   times, changing the @Tester variable each time.

```
DECLARE @empid int;
DECLARE vend_cursor CURSOR
    FOR select employee_id from employee where employee_team = 1 and employee_role = 1
OPEN vend_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM vend_cursor into @empid;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0    
BEGIN  
// your query with @mpid 
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   
END   
CLOSE vend_cursor
DEALLOCATE vend_cursor
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use cursor and it will work perfectly fine.

But, if you have significantly more than 5 rows you may consider using [`CROSS APPLY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) to make it all in one query. It may work faster than cursor.

```
select
    employee.employee_id
    ,CA.*
from
    employee
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        <put your query B here 
        and replace all references to parameter @Tester 
        with employee.employee_id>
    ) AS CA
where employee.employee_team = 1 and employee.employee_role = 1
```

You can think of this operator like this: for each row in the main outer query A `CROSS APPLY` runs the inner query B with the possibility to reference values of the row from the outer query A (in this case `employee.employee_id`).

Comment: I eliminated a lot of the complexity from query B. I have a bunch of tables in the query, each of which has multiple foreign key links to the employee table. Each metric in the query uses a different foreign key link, so the @Tester variable was the best method I could think of to make sure that I'm only calculating the metric for a given employee. In any case, I have nothing to join the CTE to in query B except by aliasing it and the employee table a bunch of times and replicating the metric logic in the join.

Comment: @Avyncentia, consider using `CROSS APPLY` instead of cursor - I changed my answer.